# Case Sensitive Spell Check and Correction for Technology names

Tags: c#, .net, spell-checking

I have 200 words of technology names (such as ASP.NET, C#, Java) which I have to spell check for proper naming conventions:
**Asp.Net becomes ASP.NET
JAVA becomes Java
Mysql becomes MySQL
Jquery becomes jQuery
Testng becomes TestNG
Nodejs becomes Node.js
Angularjs becomes AngularJS**
I used dictionary[like the link attached herewith](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5xg5.png)
But it takes around 4-5 seconds for correcting just 5 words.

My question is:
1. How to reduce the time?

Program is written in C#.

Comment: where are you stuck at?

Comment: Can we see the code you wrote to attempt to fix this?

Comment: How was replace not helpful?

Comment: Yeah we really need to see your code. [Replace works just fine to fix this issue](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SBqTTb).

Comment: Hi! I have updated the question along with the link of the snippet.

Comment: please dont change the scope of the question

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Regex.Replace, I think this is what you need ?

```
string input = "this is mYsql";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, "mysql", "MySQL", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Result is "this is MySQL"

Comment: but this would fail with `ASP.NET`...

Comment: @DanielA.White can you elaborate why ?

Comment: `ASP2NET` would match if blindly used.

Comment: @DanielA.White But the OP specifically said that it's a capitalization issue. Automatically correcting misspellings is something else entirely.

Comment: @DanielA.White [It worked fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iuSp4e)...

Comment: but the `.` in regex means match any char.

Comment: @DanielA.White Look at my fiddle. You can escape the `.` character with a backslash.

Comment: @DanielA.White I see what you mean. You'd have to regex escape the match string.

Comment: I have attached the snippet and updated the question in a more precise manner.